# nose.main hangs when testing code that uses multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, nose

I have a class that stores a function and a method that tries to run the function in parallel using the `multiprocessing` module. I'm testing the class with the `nose` module and the `nose.main()` function hangs (nothing happens, no output is displayed, the kernel must be manually told to stop and restart) when run. My directory looks like:

```
Parent/
    test.py
    Code/
        __init__.py
        code.py
    tests/
        test_code.py
```

`code.py` contains:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import itertools

def target(): pass
def target_star(args): return target(*args)

class FuncWrapper():
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun

    def run(self, X):
        try:
            arg_list_objects = []
            arg_list_inputs = []

            for i in range(len(X)):
                arg_list_objects.append(self.fun.im_self)
                arg_list_inputs.append(X[i])

            target.__code__ = self.fun.im_func.__code__

            pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()-1)

            F = np.array(pool.map(target_star, itertools.izip(arg_list_objects, arg_list_inputs))).reshape(X.shape)

            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        except:
            F = self.fun(X)

        return F
```

Most of the code in the `try:` block is used to make the `pool.map` function work with class methods.

`test_code.py` contains:

```
import numpy as np
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from Code.code import FuncWrapper

class TestCode(TestCase):

    def f(self, x):
        return x

    def test_FuncWrapper(self):
        x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (50, 1))
        return FuncWrapper(self.f).run(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`test.py` contains:

```
import nose

nose.main()
```

When I run `test_code.py` from the Parent folder, it successfully performs the test but when `test.py` is run, nothing happens. How should I use the `nose.main` function so that it doesn't hang, or is there another function in the `nose` module that would work here?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit with the Enthought Python distribution (Python 2.7.11 64-bit) and their Canopy IDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [testing python multiprocessing pool code with nose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640334/testing-python-multiprocessing-pool-code-with-nose)