# Does fork() duplicate only the calling thread or all threads?

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    fork();
    for(;i<3; ++i)
        printf("%d", i);
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. I want to know how many processes do I have after executing the last fork()

Comment: "Thread" and process should probably not be used interchangeably here. Also, please post your code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when a thread forks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890363/what-happens-when-a-thread-forks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fork splits the current process into 2 processes, so you have 2 after the first fork and 4 after the second.

Edit: After the first fork() there will be two processes, both executing the following statements. The initial process and the forked process will both call fork() the second time, resulting in 4 total processes after that call. For more info check out this link: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Comment: After the first fork() there will be two processes, both executing the following statements.  The initial process and the forked process will both call fork() the second time, resulting in 4 total processes after that call. http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Comment: The whole point is here. I don`t know if the answer is three or four

Comment: Done! Good call.